# Joins in lattices and sublattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a lattice, and $B$ be a sublattice of $A$.

Why is the join of $A$ included in the join of $B$? That is, why is $\bigcup_{t\in T}^{A} a_t\leq\bigcup_{t\in T}^{B} a_t$?

(I am tempted to think the opposite inclusion, i.e. the join of $B$, as a sublattice, is included in the join of $A$).

Comment: May be I should precise that I am considering arbitrary lattices, especially the case where infinite operations are allowed

Comment: The join of a set $S$ is the least upper bound of $S$ in the lattice, if it exists. Any upper bound in $B$ is also an upper bound in $A$, but $A$ might have an upper bound less than any upper bound in $B$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I do not understand

Comment: I’ve added a concrete example as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a concrete example. Let $A$ be $\langle\Bbb R,\le\rangle$, and let $B$ be $\langle[0,1)\cup\{2\},\le\rangle$. Then $\bigvee^A[0,1)=1$, but $\bigvee^B[0,1)=2$. (Of course in both lattices join and meet are simply $\max$ and $\min$.)

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: @student: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If a subset $B$ of a lattice $A$ is a sublattice, then by definition all joins in $B$ are the same whether they are taken in $B$ or $A$. A sublattice is the same thing as an injective homomorphism that preserves meet and join. It's true though that arbitrary meets and joins may not be preserved.

If we consider an arbitrary subset that is a lattice with possibly different meet and join, the join in $B$ will always be larger than the join in $A$ because the join in $A$ is by definition less than or equal to every element that is greater than or equal to every element in the join. This also applies for infinite lattices. The join is the smallest element dominating all of the given elements.